# How to call the jstree On function from an Angular 2 component

Tags: jquery, angular, jstree

I'm initialising a jstree from one of my angular 2 components using the below code

```
declare var $: JQueryStatic;

createTree(): void {
    $("#tree").jstree({
        "core": {
            "stripes": true
        },
        "plugins": ["types", "dnd"],
            'types': {
                "queue": {
                    "icon": "fa fa-list-ol"
                },
                "email": {
                    "icon": "fa fa-envelope-o"
                },
                "folder": {
                    "icon": "fa fa-folder-open-o"
                }
            }
        });
}
```

I had to add the `jstree` function to the JQuery interface in my `index.d.ts` file to be recognised by TypeScript

```
interface JQuery {
    jstree(options?: any): JsTree;
}
```

This function is working as expected and my tree view is generated successfully. I now want to take the next step and bind the jstree `On` function to my `JsTree` object. I added the JsTree interface

```
interface JsTree {
    on(event: string, callback: Function): void;    
}
```

and change the `createTree` method to include the `On` function

```
createTree(): void {
    $("#tree").jstree({
        "core": {
            "stripes": true
        },
        "plugins": ["types", "dnd"],
            'types': {
                "queue": {
                    "icon": "fa fa-list-ol"
                },
                "email": {
                    "icon": "fa fa-envelope-o"
                },
                "folder": {
                    "icon": "fa fa-folder-open-o"
                }
            }
        }).on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
            console.log(data.selected[0]);
        });
}
```

This however is giving me an

> TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'on'

exception. Did I declare the correct interfaces or am I missing something else?

Comment: do you have working example of this jstree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get this to work is to wrap the JsTree initialisation into it's own function in a separate javascript file and to expose the function in your Angular 2 component, below I listed the steps

Step 1 - Extract the JsTree initialisation into it's own function in a separate javascript file

```
function InitJsTree(){
    $("#tree").jstree({
        "core": {
            "stripes": true
        },
        "plugins": ["types", "dnd"],
            'types': {
                "queue": {
                "icon": "fa fa-list-ol"
            },
            "email": {
                "icon": "fa fa-envelope-o"
            },
            "folder": {
                "icon": "fa fa-folder-open-o"
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Step 2 - Remember to include the javascript file into your HTML page or into minified bundle included in your page

Step 3 - Declare the javascript function at the top of your Angular 2 component class and set it's type to `any`

```
declare var InitJsTree: any;
```

Step 4 - Use the newly exposed javascript method in your Angular 2 component

```
createTree(): void {
    InitJsTree();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with following steps while developing ionic2 app, but, I think, it should work in other cases too, as ionic2 uses angular2

1) include jquery lib in index.html along with jstree libs and css e.g.

```
<script src="lib/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/jstree/themes/default/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

2) in your component html  file declare it e.g.

```
<div id="jstree_test"></div>
```

3) in your component.ts jquery should be included like this:

```
declare var $:any;
and it is available and you can create jstree now e.g.

        $('#jstree_test').jstree({ 
            'plugins': ["ui","checkbox", "types","themes", "changed", "open_node", "sort","crrm","json_data"],
            'types': {
                'default': {
                    'icon': 'jstree-folder'
                }
            },                  
            'core' : {
                'animation' : 0,
                'check_callback':true,
                'data' : {
                    'url' : (node) => {
                            return URL;
                    },
                    'type' : 'POST',
                    'data' : (node) => {
                        return (params to be passed for URL);
                   },
                   'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', /* if json fomrat needs to be used */
                   'dataFilter': (data) => {
                        return HANDLE RESPONSE AND RETUREN JSON ARRAY TO FORM TREE;
                    },
                    'error': (e)=>{
                   }
                }
            }
        });
```

Here, I am creating JSTREE based upon AJAX Requests.